# Strange jQuery + jquery.validate + fullcalendar behaviour

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, fullcalendar, datetimepicker

I am not a jQuery expert and I need you guys to help me out here please.
I have two text boxes that allows a user to enter a datetime stamp (using datetimepicker for it), but I need to make sure the end timestamp is greater than the start one. I am using the jquery validate plug-in with a custom method for it.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("startEndCheck", function(value, element, params) {
        if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
            return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
        }   
        return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val()) || (parseFloat(value) > parseFloat($(params).val())); 
},'Must be greater than start time.');
```

This how I am defining my datetimepicker:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#start_time').datetimepicker({ ampm: true,timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss' }); 
    $('#end_time').datetimepicker({ ampm: true,timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss' }); 
    $('#ui-datepicker-div').wrap('<div class="cclicks"></div>');
    $("#end_time").rules('add', { startEndCheck: "#start_time" }); 
});
```

I also have a fullcalendar jquery plug-in added to the same page. As soon as I add the

```
$("#end_time").rules('add', { startEndCheck: "#start_time" });
```

My fullcalendar vanishes away. I am not sure how to trouble shoot this.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved by upgrading the plugins to the latest and greatest along with the latest jquery lib.

Thank you all for your help.

Nikkee